# Geo-redis, store additional data

Tags: redis

I'm using the Redis Geo API to store positions, then i fetch them with `GEORADIUS`.
Since i can only set latitude, longitude and a name for each location, how i can store and retrieve other data when i fetch locations with `GEORADIUS`?

First thing that come in my mind was to use `GEOADD` `name` as a key, and then store additional data in a normal key/value set, with the key being the same as `name`, fetch the array of positions with GEORADIUS, and loop trough that array and fetch other data using `name` as key.

Is this the correct approach or there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the other data needs to be updated/accessed, storing it in a different key (usually a Hash) makes sense. However, if the other data per `name` is immutable and accessed only in conjugation to the geo querying, you can just "embed" it after the `name`, e.g.:

```
GEOADD geoset lon lat name:data1:data2:...:datan
```

Of course, when getting the query's reply you'll have to "decode" the results and break each one back into its constituting components.

Comment: By default `GEORADIUS` return only `name`, using `WITH..`i can get coords, distance and so on. How my query will be for get everything, including embedded data? Also if i want to store an Object i have to store it as a JSON string right?

Comment: The idea is that instead of just name, you append the rest of the data to it. Then, just getting the name means getting the entire payload. JSON is a valid encoding but note that it is somewhat bloated - a better (leaner) alternative is msgpack or just a simple delimiter like in my example. Also note that with a little bit of Lua you can move the encoding and/or decoding to the server.

Comment: Okay, i was thinking that was an additional key/value. I must use `name` as an reference for deleting elements, appending data to `name` it's not something that i can do. So i think that using another set it's the only way, except if there is another way with server scripting, but i'm new to redis, and i don't know Lua.

Comment: @Fr0z3n I have same need and was thinking about same workaround you mentioned in your question. Did you come up with a better solution?